# Django on GoogleAppEngine - Performance?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, webapp2

Does running Django on GoogleAppEngine, as opposed to the default WebApp2 framework, consume additional resources? Any metrics?

Comment: webapp2 zip is 237kb, django's is 6mb (26mb uncompressed). You would be better off comparing webapp2 and flask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the mailing list, I've seen multiple comments on Django instances taking significantly longer to start up if cold.  This would be noticeable if your app is rarely used.

From my app's log it looks like the first request took about 4 seconds to start up.

My Django instances use 41-43MB.  Not sure about webapp2.

If you're using Django-nonrel as an ORM, I'm sure there's a few cycles spent in the ORM translation, but I doubt it's significant.  My Tastypie REST layer can take anywhere between 40-120ms for the same request, it looks like that performance is dictated more by the datastore than anything else.